# Sums generated with given integers

Tags: python, sum

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the different sums that can be generated with the given integers. I'm not quite getting the hang of things, and I don't really understand where and what to edit in the code.
I'm trying to follow the following rule (examples)
list [1,2,3] has 6 possible sums: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6
**list [2,2,3] has 5 possible sums: 2, 3, 4, 5 and 7**

```
list2 = [2, 2, 3] 

def sums(list2):
    if len(list2) == 1:
        return [list2[0]]
    else:
        new_list = []
        for x in sums(list2[1:]):
            new_list.append(x)
            new_list.append(x + list2[0])
        return new_list

print(sums(list2))
```

In the current code I'm struggling on getting the single integers (2, 3) and removing the duplicates. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use the concept of a set() to remove duplicates after you have your results. I would also look at the concept of permutations from itertools unless you have some specific optimization or recursion requirements. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: More of a minor code review comment, but if you do `return [list2[0]]` only when the length of the list is `1`, then you might as well just do a `return list2`

Comment: I would go for `list2.copy()`, to prevent any accidental changes to the original argument passed in when the returned list is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I found the issue. I first appended everything to the new list, and then removed the duplicates. how should I modify this more, to just get the length value of the lists, rather than the content? I  updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two things you might want to modify: (i) add the case where you append `list2[0]` itself, and (ii) use `set` to take unique numbers:

```py
def sums(list2):
    if len(list2) == 1:
        return {list2[0]}
    else:
        new_list = [list2[0]] # NOTE THAT THIS LINE HAS BEEN CHANGED
        for x in sums(list2[1:]):
            new_list.append(x)
            new_list.append(x + list2[0])
        return set(new_list)

print(sums([1,2,3])) # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
print(sums([2,2,3])) # {2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
```

Alternatively, using union operator `|`:

```py
def sums(lst):
    if not lst:
        return set()
    sums_recurse = sums(lst[1:])
    return {lst[0]} | sums_recurse | {lst[0] + x for x in sums_recurse}
```